# Get full name of SQL Server tables

Tags: c#, sql-server

Just some extract from the code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";

using (dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
     string tableName = (string)dataReader["TABLE_NAME"];
}
```

Should I use "table_schema" column of th INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES like this:

```
dbo.string fullname = dataReader["table_schema"]+"."+dataReader["table_name"];
```

Or should I use another method? I need to insert this fullname in a script for insertion table data.

Comment: No need to downvote him. This is IMHO a fair question. In fact, he is asking for the schema information, but it seems he doesn't know the term. Upvote from my side, because this is a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SchemaName = s.Name,
    TableName = t.Name,
    FullName = s.Name + '.' + t.Name
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
```

This should give you the schema, the table name, and the combined (schema).(table name) notation